# Symmetries of the multiplication of Kronecker delta and Levi-Civita symbol?

Tags: kronecker-delta

I was pondering on the symmetries that
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{ijk}\delta_{\ell m}
\end{equation}
might have upon interchanging indices of the Kronecher delta and Levi-Civita symbol, e.g. the interchange of $i$ and $m$ or $\ell$.

Following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442326/kronecker-delta-and-levi-civita-symbol) I get (see the proof below)
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{ijk}\delta_{\ell m} = \epsilon_{\boldsymbol{m}jk}\delta_{\ell \boldsymbol{i}} + \epsilon_{\boldsymbol{\ell} jk}\delta_{\boldsymbol{i} m}
\end{equation}
This seems nice, and it's something I am looking for. But if I contract both sides with $\epsilon_{ijk}$ to make sure it holds well (sanity check!), I get the obvious contradiction
\begin{equation}
6\delta_{\ell m} = 2 \delta_{im}\delta_{i\ell} + 2 \delta_{i\ell} \delta_{im} = 4 \delta_{\ell m}
\end{equation}
What could possibly have gone wrong? Also, and more importantly, what would be the symmetries anyway?

Edit:
**Proof:**

Set $\hat x_i$ as the sum (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827709/product-of-two-levi-civita-permutation-symbols/3827972#3827972))

$$\hat x_i=\delta_{i\ell}\hat x_\ell+\delta_{im}\hat x_m$$

(no summation is implied over repeated indices) so
$$\begin{align}
\epsilon_{ijk}\delta_{\ell m}&=\left(\hat x_i\cdot(\hat x_j \times \hat x_k)\right)\left(\hat x_{\ell} \cdot\hat x_m\right)\\\\
&=\left([\delta_{i\ell}\hat x_\ell+\delta_{im}\hat x_m]\cdot(\hat x_j \times \hat x_k)\right)\left(\hat x_{\ell} \cdot\hat x_m\right)\\\\
&=\delta_{i\ell}(\hat x_j \times \hat x_k)\cdot \hat x_{\ell}\hat x_{\ell}\cdot(\hat x_m)\\\\
&+\delta_{im}(\hat x_j \times \hat x_k)\cdot \hat x_{m}\hat x_{m}\cdot(\hat x_{\ell})\\\\
&=\delta_{i\ell}(\hat x_j \times \hat x_k)\cdot \hat x_m +\delta_{im}(\hat x_j \times \hat x_k)\cdot \hat x_{\ell}\\\\
&=\delta_{i\ell} \epsilon_{mjk} + \delta_{im}\epsilon_{\ell jk}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Nowhere in the linked answer is there a delta times an epsilon. So how did you get your equation?

Comment: @elemelons I added the proof. Yet as I type, I reckon I violated the completeness of $\hat{x}_i$'s as a basis. This must be the problem.

Comment: In Einstein notation, we have $\hat{x}_i=\delta_i^\ell\hat{x}_\ell$. Note that's being summed over $\ell$. I don't know why you wrote the RHS out twice with two different indices, that's wrong. But then in $(\hat{x}_i\cdot(\hat{x}_j\times\hat{x}_k))(\hat{x}_\ell\cdot\hat{x}_m)$, you replaced $\hat{x}_i$ with something that used $\ell$ as an index, even though $\ell$ was already being used as an index outside of that summation. You've confused yourself by overusing indices and not keepin track of when they are being summed over.

Comment: Compare to e.g. $3x=(\sum_{x=1}^2x)x=\sum_{x=1}^2x^2=5$, which proves three times anything is $5$. Not to mention, your current final line includes repeated indices, but the equation I asked how you got does not.

Comment: Sorry, the last line had a typo. Nothing is summed over. In the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827709/product-of-two-levi-civita-permutation-symbols/3827972#3827972) the answerer to that post provides, he specifically mentions that in $\hat x_i=\delta_{i\ell}\hat x_\ell+\delta_{im}\hat x_m$ the summation convention is NOT intended. So, it's not an expansion in the basis. Apart from that heinous typo in the last line of my proof, all indices are free.

Comment: I think I know what I did wrong! I'll post an answer and avoid editing the OP once more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the properties of the [generalized Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Properties_of_the_generalized_Kronecker_delta)
\begin{align}
3!\epsilon_{i[jk}\delta_{l]m}
&= \delta^{pqr}_{jkl}\epsilon_{ipq}\delta_{rm} \\
&= \epsilon_{jkl}\epsilon^{pqr}\epsilon_{ipq}\delta_{rm} \\
&= \epsilon_{jkl}\delta^{pqr}_{ipq}\delta_{rm} \\
&= \epsilon_{jkl}\delta^{rpq}_{ipq}\delta_{rm} \\
&= 2\epsilon_{jkl}\delta^{r}_{i}\delta_{rm} \\
&= 2\epsilon_{jkl}\delta_{im} \\
\end{align}
where the $[\dots]$ denote [antisymmetrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_tensor#Notation). Now the left hand side is
$$3!\epsilon_{i[jk}\delta_{l]m}
=
2(\epsilon_{ijk}\delta_{lm}
+\epsilon_{ikl}\delta_{jm}
+\epsilon_{ilj}\delta_{km})
$$
so dividing by $2$ you get
$$\epsilon_{ijk}\delta_{lm}
+\epsilon_{ikl}\delta_{jm}
+\epsilon_{ilj}\delta_{km}
=\epsilon_{jkl}\delta_{im}.
$$

I want to remark that I translated the first calculation in my post from [Penrose graphical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_graphical_notation). Here is my original calculation. I hope it convinces you to at least take a look at the wiki article :D it's very nice for tensor calculations.

[image: penrose graphical notation]

Comment: It's brilliant! I'm going to learn the crap out of it! I looked, and I'm going to start with [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433662/a-users-guide-to-penrose-graphical-notation) suggestions. What else would you recommend?

Comment: @Bjaam yup those resources look allright. Also take a look at the apendices in the first part of Penrose's book together with Rindler: Spinors and Space-time.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first relabel the indices for better tracking:
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{abc}\delta_{ij}
\end{equation}
Following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442326/kronecker-delta-and-levi-civita-symbol), let's assume none of the indices $(a,b,c)$ is equal to either of the other two, and hence the number $i$ is equal to one of $a$, $b$, or $c$. So, using the property of the Kronecker delta we can write

$$\hat x_i=\delta_{ia}\hat x_a+\delta_{ib}\hat x_b + \delta_{ic}\hat x_c$$

Hence,
$$\begin{align}
\epsilon_{abc}\delta_{ij}&=\left(\hat x_a\cdot(\hat x_b \times \hat x_c)\right)\left(\hat x_{i} \cdot\hat x_j\right)\\\\
&=[\hat x_a\cdot(\hat x_b \times \hat x_c)][(\delta_{ia}\hat x_a+\delta_{ib}\hat x_b + \delta_{ic}\hat x_c) \cdot\hat x_j)]\\\\
&=\delta_{ia}(\hat x_b \times \hat x_c)\cdot \hat x_{a}\hat x_{a}\cdot(\hat x_j)\\\\
&+\delta_{ib}(\hat x_c \times \hat x_a)\cdot \hat x_{b}\hat x_{b}\cdot(\hat x_{j})\\\\
&+\delta_{ic}(\hat x_a \times \hat x_b)\cdot \hat x_{c}\hat x_{c}\cdot(\hat x_{j})\\\\
&=\delta_{ia}(\hat x_b \times \hat x_c)\cdot \hat x_j + \delta_{ib}(\hat x_c \times \hat x_a)\cdot \hat x_j + \delta_{ic}(\hat x_a \times \hat x_b)\cdot \hat x_j\\\\
&= \epsilon_{jbc} \delta_{ia} + \epsilon_{ajc} \delta_{ib}+ \epsilon_{abj}\delta_{ic}
\end{align}$$